# get_image_tag() html output : empty src attribute

Tags: functions, images

I'm trying to use the `get_image_tag()` function to alter the html output of an image, like so :

```
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'kh_image_attachment', 10, 5);
function kh_image_attachment($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align) {
    $html = '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="' . esc_attr($img_src) . '" id="'.esc_attr($id).'" alt="' . esc_attr($alt) . '" title="'.esc_attr($title).'" class="'.$class.'" onload=lzld(this) onerror=lzld(this) />';
    return $html;
}
```

Unfortunately, the `src` attribute remains empty (the class attribute as well, but I couldn't care less about that). I can't for the life of me figure out why. Can you help me out here?

Thank you.

Comment: Well they will be, because you're trying to access variables that aren't set, or are outside the function [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: you shouldn't use `onload` and `onerror` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931925/what-is-the-problems-of-using-onclick-function-in-javascript

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I thought these were global variables

Comment: @janw I know, I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

I needed to use the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` function.

```
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'kh_image_attachment', 10, 5);
function kh_image_attachment($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align) {
    $image_source = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'full' );
    $html = '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="'.$image_source[0].'" id="kh-image-attachment-'.esc_attr($id).'" alt="' . esc_attr($alt) . '" title="'.esc_attr($title).'" onload=lzld(this) onerror=lzld(this) />';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: great to hear that

Answer (score 1):

try the below:
You use a filter with more then one arg, `add_filter` by default will give 1 arg, you use 4 (out of 6) in my example I am given all 6 args to your function. If you want to use 4 change your function back and change the number in the `add_filter`.

```
<?php add_filter('get_image_tag', 'kh_image_attachment', 10/*prio*/, 6/*number of arguments*/);
function kh_image_attachment($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size)
{
    //your code
}
```

It should work, questions? ask.

Comment: Ok, I'm making progress : now with your code, the alt and title attributes are showing up. However, the most crucial (the image src attribute) is still empty...